# Is it possible to play league games with the base Ninja-all-stars game?

Tags: ninja-all-stars

I'm quite interested in a very lightweight skirmish game with chibi miniatures, and it seems Ninja all-stars has it all.

What I'm wondering (and no ressources online talks about it) is, are clan boxes mandatory for league play ? Can I play Clan Ika(or whatever special clans there is) ninjas with the generic minis? Is the "core" box made only for one-shots plays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So having read the rules, I've got my game not so long ago, I'm able to answer.

The base game provides 4 teams that correspond to a shrine, which is roughly - but not exactly - the same as playing the Clan attuned to that specific element.

Without the clan box, it's impossible to play Onis (no miniatures compare in the base box), Heroes and *most* ronins. You can proxy (and in fact is the solution given by the rules) any clan with the base set - except Onis, Heroes and any ronin which happened to not be a Samurai.

So it's doable to play league games with only the base game, but is kinda hard to read, unless people limitate themselves, and not all is available even then.